# SO "User survey" breaks if you select less than 3 "most valuable aspect"(s)

Tags: bug, survey

I just got pinged to do the "SO User survey"

[image]

On the 3rd question I'm asked what I find most valuable. If you select less than 3 answers you can't continue:

[image]

I can't even rank the one answer I've selected. This needs better validation.

Comment: The idea that the Stack Overflow staff doesn't want to hear the opinions of people who can't think of three "valuable" things about Stack Overflow... actually seems just like what I'd expect.